# How to add any geom_point shapes to ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I make a heatmap within ggplot that looks something like that:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(n), y= rnorm(n), z= rnorm(n))
df$z[1:20] <- NA
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= subset(df, !is.na(z)), mapping= aes(x, y, col= z)) +
  geom_point(data= subset(df, is.na(z)), mapping= aes(x, y), col= "black", shape= 4)
```

[image: Heatmap]

Here the points of the scatterplot change colours depending on values in `z`. Further, I added black crosses (`shape` 4) to visualize missings in `z`. I want to add the same `x` as in the plot to the legend saying `missing` above it. How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually put the overall command in the same `geom_point` function using the `shape` parameter and then manually set the parameters with `scale_shape_manual`:

```r
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, colour = z, shape = is.na(z))) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Missing values", values=c(16, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: That is great! Why does it say 'values=c(16, 4)'? What do those numbers stand for?

Comment: Those number stands for the desired shapes. See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html) for more info.